# How to rotate Cubemap face without memory copy in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, video, opengl-es, render

Update for the question:

In the prior question description, I had made several serious mistakes which made the question very hard to understand and to solve. Now I will share my newest code that works.

My prior description about the direction of each face was wrong. The correct direction is as follows:
[image]

The right face is rotated 90 degrees clockwise, and the top face is rotated 180 degrees clockwise.

So when setting up the texture coordinates for the right face which is composed of two triangles (3-7-8 and 8-4-3), we need to rotate the face in the 90 degrees counter clockwise, so 3 will use 7's coordinate, 7 -> 8, 8 -> 4, 4 -> 3. When setting up the texture coordinates for the top face which is composed of two triangles(1-4-8 and 8-6-1), we need to rotate the face in 90 degrees counter clockwise, so 1 will use 8's coordinate, 4 -> 6, 8 -> 1, 6 -> 4.

The code that works:

```
    bool setupCoordinates() {
    this->vertexCount = 36;
    float skyboxVertices[] = {
        // positions          

        // back
        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,

        // Left
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
        // Right
        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        // Front
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
        // Top
        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        // Bottom
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f
    };

    float skyboxTextures[] = {
        // positions          
        // Back same as skyboxVertices
        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,

        // Left same as skyboxVertices
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,

        // Right rotate in 90 ccw
        1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,

        // Front same as skyboxVertices
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,

        // Top rotate in 180 ccw
        1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  -1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,

        // Bottom same as skyboxVertices
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f
    };

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &sceneVAO);
    glBindVertexArray(sceneVAO);

    glGenBuffers(1, &sceneVertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sceneVertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(skyboxVertices), &skyboxVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);

    glGenBuffers(1, &sceneUVBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sceneUVBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(skyboxTextures), &skyboxTextures, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void *)0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    return true;
}

void drawFrame() {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, sceneTextureID);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, videoFrameWidth);

    int width = videoFrameWidth / 3;
    int height = width;

    // back
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z, 0, GL_RGB, width, width, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

    // left
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, width);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X, 0, GL_RGB, width, width, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

    // front
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, width * 2);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z, 0, GL_RGB, width, width, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

    // bottom
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, width);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y, 0, GL_RGB, width, width, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

    // right
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, width);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, width);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, 0, GL_RGB,width,width,0,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

    // top
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, width);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, width * 2);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, 0, GL_RGB, width, width, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

}
```

------------------------------------------------Original question------------------------------------------------

I have a 360 video which is in cubemap3x2 format, and I want to render it using cubemap texture in OpenGL. However, the back and the top face of the cube, are rotated in different directions. The back face is rotated 90 degrees clockwise, and the top face is rotated 180 degrees clockwise. Now I can render the cubemap correctly by memory copy, but I wonder if there is a way to avoid this by using OpenGL's builtin capability?

The frame that I need to render:

[image]

The vertex shader:

```
#version 410 core
uniform mat4 matrix;
out vec3 TexCoords;
layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 textureIn;
void main() {
   TexCoords = textureIn;
   gl_Position = matrix * position;
}
```

The fragment shader:

```
#version 410 core
varying vec3 TexCoords;
uniform samplerCube mytexture;
void main() {
   gl_FragColor = texture(mytexture, TexCoords);
}
```

The code that I use to render:

```
void Player::SetupScene() {
this->m_sceneVertexCount = 36;
float skyboxVertices[] = {
    // positions          

    // Back
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,

    // Left
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,

    // Right
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,

    // Front
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,

    // Top
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,

    // Bottom
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f
};

float skyboxTextures[] = {
    // positions          

    // Back
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,

    // Left
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,

    // Right
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,

    // Front
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,

    // Top
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,

    // Bottom
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f
};

glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_SceneVAO);
glBindVertexArray(m_SceneVAO);

glGenBuffers(1, &m_sceneVertBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_sceneVertBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(skyboxVertices), &skyboxVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void *)0);

glGenBuffers(1, &m_sceneTexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_sceneTexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(skyboxTextures), &skyboxTextures, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void *)0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void Player::SetupTexture(unsigned char *textureData) {


     int width = frameWidth / 3;


    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, frameWidth);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, m_sceneTextureID);

    // Render left face
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z, 0, GL_RGB, width, width, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

    // Render front face
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, width);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X, 0, GL_RGB, width, width, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);


    // Render right face 
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, width * 2);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z, 0, GL_RGB, width, width, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

    // Render bottom face
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, width);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y, 0, GL_RGB, width, width, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

    // Rotate the back face 90 degrees counter clockwise 
    uint8_t *start = textureData + rowLength * height * 3 + width * 3;

    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            m_pRightFaceBuffer[((width - 1 - i) * width + j) * 3 + 0] = *(start + i * 3 + 0);
            m_pRightFaceBuffer[((width - 1 - i) * width + j) * 3 + 1] = *(start + i * 3 + 1);
            m_pRightFaceBuffer[((width - 1 - i) * width + j) * 3 + 2] = *(start + i * 3 + 2);
        }
        start += rowLength * 3;
    }

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, width);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, 0, GL_RGB, width, width, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_pRightFaceBuffer);

    // Rotate the bottom face 180 degrees counter clockwise
    start = textureData + rowLength * height * 3 + width * 2 * 3;
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            m_pUpFaceBuffer[((height - 1 - j)*width + (width - i)) * 3 + 0] = *(start + (i) * 3);
            m_pUpFaceBuffer[((height - 1 - j)*width + (width - i)) * 3 + 1] = *(start + (i) * 3 + 1);
            m_pUpFaceBuffer[((height - 1 - j)*width + (width - i)) * 3 + 2] = *(start + (i) * 3 + 2);
        }
        start += rowLength * 3;
    }

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, 0, GL_RGB, width, width, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_pUpFaceBuffer);

}
```

The coordinate that I use to build the cubemap:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly specify the sides of the cubemap by [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml):

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, frameWidth);

// Render left face
[...]

// Render front face
[...]

// Render right face 
[...]

// Render bottom face
[...]

// Render back face
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, width);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, width);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, 0, GL_RGB, width, width, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

// Render top face
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, width);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, width*2);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, 0, GL_RGB, width, width, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);
```

But you have to change the texture coordinates for right and top side. Note you messed up the mapping of the cube map sides to the sides of the cube, but anyway it works:

```
float skyboxTextures[] = {
    // positions          

    // Back
    // [...]

    // Left
    // [...]

    // Right
    1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,

    // Front
    // [...]

    // Top
     1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,

    // Bottom
    // [...]
};
```

See the result:

[image]
[image]

---

Since the mapping of the sides seems to be messed up, I would prefer to load the sides like this:

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, frameWidth);

// Render back face
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, width);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, width);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z, 0, GL_RGB, width, width, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

// Render left face
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X, 0, GL_RGB, width, width, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

// Render right face 
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, width * 2);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, 0, GL_RGB, width, width, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

// Render front face
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, width);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z, 0, GL_RGB, width, width, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

// Render top face
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, width);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, width*2);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, 0, GL_RGB, width, width, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

// Render bottom face
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, width);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y, 0, GL_RGB, width, width, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);
```

and to use the following texture coordinates:

```
float skyboxTextures[] = {
    // positions          

    // Back
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,

    // Left
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,

    // Right
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,

    // Front
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,

    // Top
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,

    // Bottom
     1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f
};
```

But note, the y and the z axis are still swapped. I assume this is because the world space up vector in your scene is (0, 1, 0).

Comment: I tried your method, however it did not work. Maybe it's caused by the difference of the coordinate system. I will continue working on this. Thank you!

Comment: I tried to adjusted the texture coordinates according to your suggestions, but no matter how I changed the order of the texture coordinates or glTexImage2D order, the rendered image is always wrong. Dose the order the definition of the texture coordinates must be the same with the glTexImage2D order?

Comment: @Tamarous The 1st solution in my answer, is the minimal code which fixes the issue in your question. Just swap this parts of your code.